# Installing Windows 7 hide Ubuntu on my machine

Tags: dual-boot

I had Ubuntu installed on my laptop. I installed Windows 7 and now I can't access Ubuntu.  But the partition is there. I thought I would get a choice of operating systems at the start but I don't. I want them both. How do I get a choice of operating systems during system start up?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows  and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Steps:

- Boot from a Ubuntu LiveCD.
- Select Try Ubuntu.
- Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>).
- Execute the following commands:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install boot-repair sudo boot-repair
  ```
- Follow the instructions.
- Reboot.

This will re-install GRUB, which was removed by the Windows installer. You'll be able to boot into both operating systems now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot from the live CD.
2. Determine the partition number of your main partition. GParted can help you here. I'm going to assume in this answer that it's `/dev/sda2`, but *make sure you use the correct partition number for your system!*
3. Mount your partition:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt  # make sure that sda2 is correct!
   ```
4. Bind mount some other necessary stuff:

   ```
   for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done
   ```
5. `chroot` into your Ubuntu install:

   ```
   sudo chroot /mnt
   ```
6. At this point, you're in your install, not the live CD, and running as root. Update grub:

   ```
   update-grub
   ```

   If you get errors, go to step 7. (Otherwise, it is optional.)
7. Depending on your situation, you might have to reinstall grub:

   ```
   grub-install /dev/sda
   update-grub
   ```
8. If everything worked without errors, then you're all set:

   ```
   exit
   sudo reboot
   ```